# Android - parsing specific XML parts

Tags: android, xml, parsing, tags

Hello I want to parse http://jon-stevens.com/rss/index.php

Im using

```
 public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        String text = null;
        try {

            event = myParser.getEventType();
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = myParser.getName();
                switch (event) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if ((name.equals("description"))&&(text.contains("Week"))) {
                        title=text;
                    }else if((name.equals("title"))&&(text.contains(tagz.toUpperCase()))){

                            country=text;       
                    }
                    break;
                }

                event = myParser.next();

            }
            parsingComplete = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Where tagz is string value of specific horoscope sign(example: " Aries" )
I dont know how to parse the description of every horoscope sign on button click(which carries the tagz). So far I parse the initial horoscope description (" Week beginning Mon., Jan 27th and ending Sun., Feb 2nd, 2014") and horoscope sign titles but how can i get the specific sign description(description for the specific zodiac sign of the tile i parse) aswell?

Answer (score 0):

In START_TAG, check for "item" - this signifies a start of a horoscope. Set a flag.  Then in END_TAG, if the flag is set, the Title and description relate to a horoscope.  You can perhaps use a HashMap to store the horoscope (after parsing the title for the horoscope name).

Remember to clear the flag on END_TAG  is an "item".

Comment: Isnt there a way to move to the 2nd tag after the specific title and get its content(since description is 2 tags below title). I dont really need to parse the title im just having it as a check to get the appropriate zodiac sign on button click. I dont really understand the flag thing. I mean yes both title and description are in an item tag but i still dont know how to get the description. Sorry thats my first application and im kinda slow on processing information ;p

Comment: The parser will find each tag in turn.  The 'event' indicates a START or END_TAG, and the 'name' indicates which tag it is.  You can't really skip around within the XML document, you have to take things as they come, serially. So, once you see the 'item' tag, you know that the next "title" and "description" tags refer to an item - that's where the flag comes in.